# How to define structure in VBA? Alternative to Delphi "record" command

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-types

I am Newbie to VBA. I would like to define my own structure, just like in Delphi is something like:

```pascal
type Name = Record
    Declarations ...
end;
```

For example in Delphi I would write:

```pascal
type TNUMBER = Record
    value: integer;
    min: integer;
    max: integer;
    count: byte;
    processed: boolean;
end; 

var my_numbers: array[0..74] of TNUMBER;
i: integer;
range: byte;
begin
range := 7;
for i:=0 to 74 do
  if not my_numbers[i].processed then
    begin
      my_numbers[i].value := round(somenumber);
      my_numbers[i].min := my_numbers[i].value-range;    
      my_numbers[i].max := my_numbers[i].value+range;
      my_numbers[i].count := 0;
    end
  else
    begin
      if (somenumber >= my_numbers[i].min) AND
         (somenumber <= my_numbers[i].max) then
        begin
          inc(my_numbers[i].count);  ' increase counter
        end;
    end;
```

So I have declared the type or structure `TNUMBER`, which contains various members. Then I created array of this type and I process numbers and change the records referred by variable `my_numbers`. So I need to create similar structure for VBA to count numbers obtained from Excel cells. The purpose of this structure is to calculate if the numbers are too close each other or if they are far enough to (decide whether to) draw a point or circle on my chart drawings.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rewrite your example in VBA like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TNUMBER 'Or Public if needed in another module
    value As Integer
    min As Integer
    max As Integer
    count As Byte
    processed As Boolean
End Type

Public Sub test()
    Dim my_numbers(0 To 74) As TNUMBER
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim range As Byte
    Dim somenumber As Double

    range = 7
    For i = 0 To 74
        If Not my_numbers(i).processed Then
            my_numbers(i).value = Round(somenumber)
            my_numbers(i).min = my_numbers(i).value - range
            my_numbers(i).max = my_numbers(i).value + range
            my_numbers(i).count = 0
        Else
            If (somenumber >= my_numbers(i).min) And _
               (somenumber <= my_numbers(i).max) Then
                my_numbers(i).count = my_numbers(i).count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

and then you would of course execute the `test` method.

Also, you would not want to use:
`For i = 0 To 74`
but instead you would use:
`For i = LBound(my_numbers) To UBound(my_numbers)`
so that if the array size changes the code still runs.

Comment: Thank you so much. I search the MS support and they wrote to LBound: "Returns a Long containing the smallest available subscript for the indicated dimension of an array." What does mean the "subscript"? Do they mean the first element in an array?

Comment: not the first element, but the first index of the array. For example, if your array is `Dim a(2 To 5)` the Lbound will be 2 and the Ubound will be 5. Lbound and Ubound also have a optional second parameter for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @JohnBoe Vincent provided the answer, I only tagged you so that you get notified

Comment: @VincentG: If I want to create new record in the array (when it is empty, should I use Redim? As found example: `ReDim arr(0 To col.Count-1) As TNUMBER`?

Comment: @JohnBoe `ReDim Preserve ...` if you want to keep the current data in the resized array.